# Finding Gaps in Hundred Range Street Centerline Segments in GIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, address

Is there a way to find gaps for Hundred Range Street Centerline Segments within the attribute table?

An example that I can think of, is if there is a hundred range street segment that shows 1001-1049 W Adams St and the following centerline segment shows 1071-1099 W Adams St. The missing data can effect our composite address locator and create other issues when there is a gap in the hundred ranges. I

f there was a capability to find which centerline hundred ranges are not continuous within our database it would be useful.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't appear the `ADDRESSERRORS` command available in ARC/INFO ever got ported to ArcGIS. Have you tried this AddressErrors toolbox? https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d34959c8f11940c08143440e7fcf585e

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the ranges to values using python.  Then you can compare the continuity of the ranges.

Create two new fields - value1 and value2

In field calculator for value1:

codeblock

```
def rangetovalue(strange, value1):
    return strange.split('-')[0]
```

expression

```
rangetovalue(!range!, !value1!)
```

In field calculator for value2:

codeblock

```
def rangetovalue(strange, value2):
    return strange.split('-')[1]
```

expression

```
rangetovalue(!range!, !value2!)
```

If you have 10932-10999 in the range field, value1 will get 10932 and value2 will get 10999.

Now you will have to figure out how you want to compare the values.

I suggest that you copy the attributes into excel.

- Sort the table on Street Name and Value1.
- Shift 'Value2' down 1 row.
- Calculate into a new column: Value1-Value2.

If the result is anything other than zero, you know you have a gap.

I hope this helps.